# How i can speedUP my events based procedure?

Tags: performance, vba, events

i have huge problem with my event procedure, it takes ages to run when i want to change more than few cells at once. How it works, well when user changes data in cell the Worksheet_Change adds comments, but first the Worksheet_SelectionChange updates informations for user (i have sumifs in different worksheet where it calculates ACT date for 12 months, and then it display via camer tool on active worksheet).

In know that problem is cuz of constant looping through events.... duno what to do ?!

Thx for help!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xyz"

For Each cell In Target

        If cell.Row > 21 And cell.Column > 9 Then

            If cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                cell.AddComment Now & " - " & cell.Value & " - " & Application.UserName
            Else
                If Val(Len(cell.Comment.Text)) > 255 Then
                    cell.Comment.Delete
                    cell.AddComment
                    cell.Comment.Text _
                    Now & " - " & cell.Value & " - " & Application.UserName, 1 _
                    , False
                Else
                    cell.Comment.Text _
                    vbNewLine & Now & " - " & cell.Value & " - " & Application.UserName, Len(cell.Comment.Text) + 1 _
                    , False
                End If
            End If

        cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        End If

Next cell

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="11opkLnm890", AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RowNumber As Long, i As Long
Dim MaxRowNumber As Long

MaxRowNumber = Range("A9").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

RowNumber = Target.Row

Set sh_AUXILIARY_PT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AUXILIARY_PT")

    If Target.Row > 21 And Target.Row < MaxRowNumber Then

        sh_AUXILIARY_PT.Range("AA4").Value = Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value
        sh_AUXILIARY_PT.Range("AB4").Value = Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value
        sh_AUXILIARY_PT.Range("AC4").Value = Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value
        sh_AUXILIARY_PT.Range("AD4").Value = Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value

        For i = 14 To 25

        sh_AUXILIARY_PT.Cells(8, i).Value = Cells(RowNumber, i - 4).Value

        Next i

    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you may consider assigning your collection range to an Array and then loop through since Arrays are much faster.